# How to install default photo app?

Tags: release-loki

I'd like to install again default photo application of elementary os because i have deleted it, i tried to search it in application center but it doesn't show there. What command should i use to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo apt-get install pantheon-photos` :)